# How do I ensure I won't replace a content to an old response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, promise

Good day for all,

I am doing a React course and I'd submited the code to the reviewer. He's returned me few comments and there is one comment I'm not being able to solve.

The comment is the following:

> Check if (query === this.state.query) to ensure you are not going to replace the contents to an old response

And part of the code is the one below:

```
updateQuery = (query) => {

        this.setState({

          query: query

        })

        this.updateWantedBooks(query);
      }

updateWantedBooks = (query) => {

        if (query) {

          BooksAPI.search(query).then((wantedBooks) => {

            if (wantedBooks.error) {

              this.setState({ wantedBooks: [] });

            } else {

this.setState({ wantedBooks: wantedBooks });

            }       

          })

        } else {

          this.setState({ wantedBooks: [] });

        }

      }
```

Anyone could help me what do am I suppose to do?

Regards.

Comment: Without seeing the full code, it sounds like in your if statement you just need to replace `if(query)` with `if(query && query !== this.state.query)`.

Comment: Wait, I'll put the code more complete.

Comment: I Had edited the main question.

Comment: See my response & kind user's response below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of relying on an outer member which is open to abuse by other code, you can employ a factory function to more safely trap a member.

As you have discovered, trapping and testing `query == this.state.query` can be made to work but is arguably not the best solution available.

With a little thought, you can force each call of `updateWantedBooks()` automatically to reject the *previous* promise returned by the same function (if it has not already settled), such that any success callbacks chained to the *previous* promise don't fire its error path is taken.

This can be achieved with a reusable `canceller` utility that accepts two callbacks and exploits [Promise.race()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race), as follows:

```
// reusable cancellation factory utility
function canceller(work, successCallback) {
    var cancel;
    return async function(...args) {
        if (cancel) {
            cancel(new Error('cancelled')); // cancel previous
        }
        return Promise.race([
            work(...args),
            new Promise((_, reject) => { cancel = reject }) // rejectable promise
        ]).then(successCallback);
    };
};
```

Here's a demo ...

```js
// reusable cancellation factory utility
function canceller(work, successCallback) {
 var cancel;
 return async function(...args) {
  if (cancel) {
   cancel(new Error('cancelled')); // cancel previous
  }
  return Promise.race([
   work(...args),
   new Promise((_, reject) => { cancel = reject })
  ]).then(successCallback);
 };
};

// delay utility representing an asynchronous process
function delay(ms, val) {
 return new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(resolve, ms, val);
 });
};

function MySpace() {
 // establish a canceller method with two callbacks
 this.updateWantedBooks = canceller(
  // work callback
  async (query) => delay(500, query || { 'error': true }), // a contrived piece of work standing in for BooksAPI.search()
  // success callback
  (wantedBooks => this.setState(wantedBooks)) // this will execute only if work() wins the race against cancellation
 );
 this.setState = function(val) {
  console.log('setState', val);
  return val;
 };
};

var mySpace = new MySpace();
mySpace.updateWantedBooks({'value':'XXX'}).then(result1 => { console.log('result', result1) }).catch(error => { console.log(error.message) }); // 'cancelled'

mySpace.updateWantedBooks(null).then(result2 => { console.log('result', result2) }).catch(error => { console.log(error.message) }); // 'cancelled'

mySpace.updateWantedBooks({'value':'ZZZ'}).then(result3 => { console.log('result', result3) }).catch(error => { console.log(error.message) }); // {'value':'ZZZ'} (unless something unexpected happened)
```

Note that `canceller()` doesn't attempt to abort the asynchronous process it initiates, rather it stymies the success path of the returned promise in favour of the error path.

Comment: Thanks, @Roamer-1888. I'll test your approach and see what happens. I won't do this at this time, because I've received some other comments by reviewer easier to implement, so I'll do these implementations first an then work in your idea. I advise you here if it works. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Code reviewer is right, you don't really want to replace the response if user has entered the very same query.

You have to store somewhere what for user has searched recently:

```
this.setState({ wantedBooks: [], query });
```

In case of success response:

```
this.setState({ wantedBooks, query });
```

And then check it in case of further searches:

```
if (query && query !== this.state.query) {
    // continue the search only if query is different that current
```

Comment: Hi, @kinduser. Sorry, but I hadn't figured out yet. 

Please, if wouldn't be bothering for you, where exactly do I put these statements?

Regards.

Comment: @jose-renato-m It's quite simple, just replace my third code sample with yours `if (query) {`, my second code sample with yours `this.setState({ wantedBooks: wantedBooks });` and my first code sample with yours `this.setState({ wantedBooks: [] });`

Comment: Dear @kinduser. Sorry to bother you again. I'm not 100% it is working well.

I did some tests and the code behavior is strange. I've found out other reviewer comment; he said the following (in other part of comments form I haven't read yet): >Inside 'then' part of the promise check if(query === this.state.query) to ensure you are not going to replace the contents to an old response.

I've got intrigued with this "inside 'then'" reported by reviewer.

Comment: @jose-renato-m see my answer regarding "Inside 'then' part of the promise check if(query === this.state.query) to ensure you are not going to replace the contents to an old response" (c) It describes the risk of showing of outdated response in case of multiple searches in a row

Answer (score 0):

I think reviewer's point is that response of Search API is asynchronous and result for "query 1" can arrive after user changed his mind and already requested search "query 2". So when response arrive - we need to check if we really interested in it:

```
 updateQuery = query => {
    this.setState({
      query: query
      wantedBooks: []
    })
    this.updateWantedBooks(query);
  }

updateWantedBooks = query => {
    if (query) {
      BooksAPI.search(query).then((wantedBooks) => {
        // if updateQuery("query1) and updateQuery("query2") called in a row
        // then response for query1 can arrive after we requested query2
        // => for some period of time we'll show incorrect search results
        // so adding check if query still the same can help
        if (query !== this.state.query) {
          // outdated response
          return;
        } else if (wantedBooks.error) {
           // query is okay, but server error in response
           this.setState({
              wantedBooks: []
           })
        } else {
           // success response to requested query
           this.setState({ wantedBooks });
        }
     })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys I´ve done some tests with your answers, but I realize that somehow the code was behavioring strangely.

So, I've seen in other part of the reviewer comments, a part which I hadn't had seen before do my answer here, the following comment:

> Inside **'then'** part of the promise check if(query === this.state.query) to ensure you are not going to replace the contents to an old response.

And this "Inside 'then'" has been beating in my brain.

So, I think I've arrived in a satisfatory code; sure, maybe it isn't the definite solution, that's why I want to show here for you and feel free to comment if I'd have to make some improvement. Here below I put the code:

```
updateQuery = (query) => {

        this.setState({

          query: query

        })

        this.updateWantedBooks(query);

      }


      updateWantedBooks = (query) => {

        if (query) {

          BooksAPI.search(query).then((wantedBooks) => {

            if (wantedBooks.error) {

              this.setState({ wantedBooks: [] });

            } else if (query !== this.state.query) {

              this.setState( { wantedBooks: [] });

            } else {

              this.setState({ wantedBooks: wantedBooks });

            } 

          })

        } else {

          this.setState({ wantedBooks: [] });

        }    

      }
```

Regards